# Div height on the basis of the other div height

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add a div whose height depends on the length of another div.

For example a **DIV A** have some content and **DIV B** contains content representing the feedback for DIV. If the **DIV B** has more content than the length **DIV A** should be shown as scrollable instead of expanding its height.

```html
<div class="A col-md-9">
content
</div>
<div class="B col-md-3">
feedback content
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show a working example of your problem?

Comment: Maybe `<div class="A col-md-9">`? (for the 2nd div as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it through CSS `flex`. You can read more on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also, you should add these `A col-md-9` inside a class like this `<div class="A col-md-9">`, for now I have restructured the code.

```css
.parent {
display: flex;
}
.A, .B {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="A col-md-9">
  content<br>More Content<br> And more content...
  </div>
  <div class="B col-md-9">
  feedback content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you must set the same height for both div then make `overflow: auto` and add another div inside them

```
<div class="A col-md-9">
    <div>
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="B col-md-3">
    <div>
        feedback content
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.A {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.B {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Update: if you want to have height based on A div you need to get A div height first and set that height to B div

```
const height = document.getElementsByClassName('A')[0].offsetHeight;
document.getElementsByClassName('B')[0].style.height = height + 'px';
```

and then you do not need to add height in A and B class

```
.A, .B {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

know you set height on B div base on A div content if B div has more content it shows in scroll view mode and instead of expanding its height.

this works for me